# Problem renaming constraint from code behind

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to rename the constraint of an SQL Server table from code in a Windows Form (VS2019).

This is the code.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"EXEC sys.sp_rename @objname = N'[dbo].[@OldConstraint]', @newname = [@NewConstraint], @objtype = N'OBJECT';", sqlConnection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OldConstraint", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = oldConstraintName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NewConstraint", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = newConstraintName;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I execute the command, obtain the error:

> Either the parameter@objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.

The error, I suppose, depends on the fact that in the query there is @object which is considered a parameter, starting with the @ character

I know I could write the command like this...

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC sys.sp_rename @objname = N'[dbo].[" + oldConstraintName + "]', @newname = [" + newConstraintName + "], @objtype = N'OBJECT';", sqlConnection);
```

and everything would work fine, but in this case I have the warning

> CA2100: Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities

Do you have any idea how to solve my problem?
Thank you, everyone.

Skyns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use parameterized query, you don't need wrap parameter with ' :

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"EXEC sys.sp_rename @objname = @OldConstraint, @newname = @NewConstraint, @objtype = N'OBJECT';", sqlConnection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OldConstraint", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = oldConstraintName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NewConstraint", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = newConstraintName;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you.
The problem was caused by the square brackets. Remove the wrapping brackets and the character ', it works!!!!
`
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"EXEC sys.sp_rename @objname = @OldConstraint, @newname = @NewConstraint, @objtype = N'OBJECT';", sqlConnection);
`

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has quite surprising syntax rules in places. View the documentation for [`EXEC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
Execute a stored procedure or function  
[ { EXEC | EXECUTE } ]  
    {   
      [ @return_status = ]  
      { module_name [ ;number ] | @module_name_var }   
        [ [ @parameter = ] { value   
                           | @variable [ OUTPUT ]   
                           | [ DEFAULT ]   
                           }  
        ]  
      [ ,...n ]  
      [ WITH <execute_option> [ ,...n ] ]  
    }  
[;]
```

Note, each parameter value can be passed as a *value* or as a *variable*. You're not allowed to use arbitrary expressions.

Note also that:

> @object which is considered a parameter

isn't true in general. Parameters aren't find & replace in disguise. A string *containing* an `@` symbol is just that, a string containing a `@`. No parameter value will be substituted into such a string. So your string `N'[dbo].[@OldConstraint]'` is literally just that string.

You should pass the *entire* string you want to use as the parameter value, as [Vernou shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63518239/15498).